# Unicode, char pointers and wcslen

Tags: c++, unicode, wchar-t

I've been trying to use the cpw library for some graphics things. I got it set up, and I seem to be having a problem compiling.
  Namely, in a string header it provides support for unicode via

```
#if defined(UNICODE) | defined(_UNICODE)
#define altstrlen wstrlen
#else
#define altstrlen strlen
```

Now, there's no such thing as wstrlen on Windows afaik, so I tried changing that to wcslen, but now it gives me and error because it tried to convert a char * to a wchar_t *. I'm kinda scared that if I just had it use strlen either way, something else would screw up.

What do you think stackoverflow?

Comment: Did you check if the string that is being passed to altstrlen is a UNICODE string? It should either use the L"str" qualifier or should use the _T("str") macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can define `wcslen` as `wstrlen` before including the lib header:

```
#define wstrlen wcslen
#include "cpw.h"
```

The error you are getting is likely to be due to you passing a `char*` that into something that ends up calling one of those functions.

Comment: I checked over the library source, and it turns out they didn't follow their own format. Swapping their char * with wchar_t * when the macro was defined helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your data is char* based to begin with, then there is no need to call a Unicode version of strlen(), just use the regular strlen() by itself, since it takes char* as input.  Unless your char* data is actually UTF-8 encoded and you are trying to determine the unencoded Unicode length, in which case you need to decode the UTF-8 first before then calling wcslen().

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Unicode on Windows, you need to change all of your character types to `wchar_t`. That means, instead of:

```
char *str = "Hello World";
int len = strlen(str);
```

You need:

```
wchar_t *str = L"Hello World";
int len = wcslen(str);
```

Notice that the character type has been changed to `wchar_t` and the string literal is prefixed with `L`.

Comment: Thing is, this isn't my code, I'm using cpw window library for OpenGL.
http://www.mathies.com/cpw/about.html . I'm just wondering what I should do about it (ie go through the library and change all the char to wchar_t, use strlen and hope for the best, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio already has such macros, see `tchar.h`.

```
#include <tchar.h>

TCHAR *str = _T("Sample text");
int len = _tcslen(str);
```

-- will work in ANSI, MBCS and UNICODE mode depending on compiler settings.

For more details see **[this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx)**.